# How to insert UTC datetimes to closedXML?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

In the c# closedXML plugin, I get this message

```
Unable to set cell value to 10/27/2017 10:14:23 AM +00:00
```

c#

```
    public static async Task<string> SaveToExcel(string command, Dictionary<string, object> h, string domain, string sheet_name, string[] headers)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(domain));
        await myConnection.OpenAsync();

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(command, myConnection);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in h)
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(entry.Key, entry.Value ?? DBNull.Value);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myCommand.CommandText);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(dt);

        // add headers
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); 
        for(int i=0; i<headers.Length; i++)
        {
            //dr[i] = headers[i];
        }
        //dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

        string filepath = Excel.SaveExcel(dt, sheet_name);

        dt.Dispose();
        sda.Dispose();
        myCommand.Dispose();
        myConnection.Close();

        return filepath;
    }

    public static string SaveExcel(System.Data.DataTable dt, string SheetName)
    {
        // create the Excel workbook
        var wb = new XLWorkbook();

        // creates the worksheet
        var ws = wb.AddWorksheet(SheetName);

        // add data
        ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(dt);

        // the range for which you want to add a table style
        var range = ws.Range(1, 1, dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count);

        // create the actual table
        var table = range.CreateTable();

        // adjust size
        ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();

        // apply style
        table.Theme = XLTableTheme.TableStyleMedium5;

        // save file as temp
        string result = Path.GetTempFileName();
        wb.SaveAs(result);

        return result;
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a bug in ClosedXML. If you log an issue in the Github repository and complete the template very thoroughly, I will try to fix it.

Comment: ok I have added it https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/1473